# Raspberry pi 4B doesnt boot after systemctl reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi

I rebooted my rpi 4b with the following command: `sudo systemctl reboot`, and it did turn off, but wasn't rebooting after about an hour and a half (i had rebooted it perfectly before) so I decided to cut the power off and on, and try to login via ssh, but the green LED it blinked quickly and stopped after a long blink. I tried looking up answers but didn't find anything, I also tried removing and re-creating the FAT32 partitions, but I got the same LED pattern. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [raspberrypi.se], as it is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to reboot the raspi then you simply need `reboot` or `sudo reboot`. `systemctl` is something else entirely and responsible for running services on your pi.

Comment: That is what I intended, but it doesn't start up correctly after I typed sudo systemctl reboot - I was on ssh and it appeared to kick me out and restart

Comment: But you should not put `systemctl`, just `reboot`

Comment: It should still work with systemctl but worth trying without to see if there’s any difference.  What OS are you running? Are you sure the power supply is powerful enough? Could the SD card be corrupt?

Comment: I was running raspbian OS, but after I searched the LED codes for this and it was either Partition not FAT or File signature/hash mismatch (not sure because there was flickering)